# Difference Between Using Preimage Pallet and Hash Storage with T::Hashing in Substrate

Tags: pallet, storage

I'm working on a project using Substrate and have encountered a technical question regarding data storage. I would like to understand the fundamental difference between using the `Preimage` pallet and storing a data hash using `T::Hashing`.

1. What are the specific use cases where it is more advantageous to use the `Preimage` pallet over simply creating a data hash with `T::Hashing`?
2. Are there any differences in terms of performance or security between these two methods?
3. How does memory management differ between these two approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much difference between them.

`Preimage` is more of a general version. It offers a place for those who don't want to store this themselves, and it provides a calculation for the general storage cost fee. And it also has a nice UI on Polkadot Apps for people to review the existing items.

If you have a lot of specific logic, it's best to write it yourself.

In terms of memory management, you can't keep a long-lifetime variable in the runtime. There are many tasks that need to be completed within a block.